# Split value and place separated value into two different column using mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to split two values which is separated by multiplication symbol for example  "12X36"  after split it should get 12 in one column 36 in one column i.e 'X' symbol removed from those numbers get get final values in separate column for every record in Mysql

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('12X36','X',2)
```

but this is eliminating 'X', I want to show 12 in separate column and 36 in separate column but don't know further step

expected output:

```
1) 12X36
2) 23X40

column1         column2
  12             36
  23             40
```

getting output

SUBSTRING_INDEX('12X36','X',2)

12

Comment: Substring(substring....),'x',-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, many ways. Here is one using LEFT and RIGHT

```
SELECT LEFT('12X36', LOCATE('X', '12X36') - 1), RIGHT('12X36', LOCATE('X', '12X36') - 1)
```

and one using reg exp, here the substrings are all digits from the start (denoted by ^) up to a non-digit and all digit between the last noon-digit and the end of the string (indented by $)

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('12X36', '^[0-9]*'), REGEXP_SUBSTR('12X36', '[0-9]*$')
```

Comment: working as per my expectation,can you please explain this.

Comment: I added an explanation of the reg exp variant .

Comment: @MASamad: [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) in MySQL >= 8.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways. One is to `locate()` the `'X'` and `substring()` around it.

```
SELECT substring('12X36', 1, locate('X', '12X36') - 1),
       substring('12X36', locate('X', '12X36') + 1)
```